# How to sort values in pandas pivot table and plot them?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pivot

I have a pivot table (i.e):

```
City                   Atlanta     New York   Chicago
Region name              Slow        Grid       Fathe

2010-01                  1            2          3
2010-02                  3            15         23   
...                                   ...
2016-01                  12           1          0
```

when I try to plot some values with the following:

```
pivot.ix['2016-01'].plot(kind='barh', 
                        figsize=(7, 10), 
                        width=0.8, 
                        fontsize=10, 
                        colormap='autumn')
```

I get the following graph:
[image]

How to change the code to plot this graph ascendingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding .sort_values() in between the pivot.ix[] and the .plot() calls will sort the Series returned by .ix[] before it's plotted and should give you the result you want.

```
pivot.ix['2016-01'].sort_values().plot(kind='barh', 
                                       figsize=(7, 10), 
                                       width=0.8, 
                                       fontsize=10, 
                                       colormap='autumn')
```